# Handling failed HTTP responses with fetch and async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I use this code to handle failed requests with fetch (by throwing Error):

```
function asyncCall() {
    fetch("https://httpstat.us/500")
    .then(function(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.text(); // or .json();
    })
    .then(function(text) {
        console.log("ok", text);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("error", error); 
    })

}

asyncCall();
```

Now I am interested on how async/await version of this code could look like, and this what I came with:

```
async function syncCall() {
  let response = await fetch("https://httpstat.us/200")
  if (response.ok) return await response.text()
  throw new Error(response.statusText)
}

async function callFetch() {
  try {
      let text = await syncCall()
      console.log(text)
  } catch(e) {
      console.log("error", e); 
  }
}

callFetch()
```

Is this code good, is there some nicer, shorter way?

Comment: this is how it should be done, if you don't handle `async ... await` like that i.e using `try...catch` block , you are going to get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`